# Which color weight do we get from $primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo)?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

When we do:

```
$primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
```

Which color do we get (500?)?  The color swatches are at the bottom of this document:

https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#tools-for-picking-colors

We can ask for weights specifically like this:

```
$my-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange, A200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with [angular/components](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/caad0b54ed41949f0ee529c152508749875bc9af/src/material/core/theming/_theming.scss#L19) source code

`mat-palette` return a set of colors based on material design guidelines.
they are `default`, `lighter`, `darker`, `text`, `default-contrast`, `lighter-contrast`, `darker-contrast` and more...

This function has the next params

`@function mat-palette($base-palette, $default: 500, $lighter: 100, $darker: 700, $text: $default)`

#### First question

It doesnt return one color as explain above. However the `default` is mapped with `#3f51b5` by default from [mat-indigo source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/caad0b54ed41949f0ee529c152508749875bc9af/src/material/core/theming/_palette.scss#L177)

#### Second one question

Yes you can pass a param asking for weight

On your example `default` will be mapped with `#ff6e40` from [mat-deep-orange source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/caad0b54ed41949f0ee529c152508749875bc9af/src/material/core/theming/_palette.scss#L546)